# Where to find a full analysis of the encryption scheme of CTB-Locker?

Tags: tools, malware, cryptanalysis, ransomware

CTB-Locker is a currently active ransomware that encrypts files to lock users out.

Here are a few links about this malware:

- [A new generation of ransomware: Elliptic curve cryptography + Tor + Bitcoin](http://securelist.com/analysis/publications/64608/a-new-generation-of-ransomware/), by Fedor Sinitsyn, July 24, 2014.
- [CTB-Locker: Multilingual Malware Demands Ransom](http://www.eset.com/int/about/press/eset-blog/article/ctb-locker-ransomware-striking-in-europe-and-latin-america/), by Pablo Ramos, January 21, 2015.
- [CTB-Locker Ransomware Includes Freemium Feature, Extends Deadline](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/ctb-locker-ransomware-includes-freemium-feature-extends-deadline/), by Trend Micro, January 21, 2015.
- [CTB Locker and Critroni Ransomware Information Guide and FAQ](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/ctb-locker-ransomware-information), by Lawrence Abrams, January 29, 2015.
- [CTB-Locker: files decryption demonstration feature](https://zairon.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/ctb-locker-files-decryption-demonstration-feature/), by Zairon, February 9, 2015.
- [CTB-Locker dropper](http://christophe.rieunier.name/securite/CTB-Locker/CTB-Locker_analysis_en.php), by Christophe Rieunier.
- [decryptcryptolocker.com](https://www.decryptcryptolocker.com/), by FireEye and Fox IT (doesn't seems to work for CTB-Locker).
- [CryptoLocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker), Wikipedia (a similar Ransomware).

Is there a complete analysis about the encryption used by CTB-Locker, and some hints about possible cryptanalysis based on some weaknesses of this cryptographic scheme that can be used to recover the encrypted files.

The idea would be to produce a (free) tool similar to [decryptcryptolocker.com](https://www.decryptcryptolocker.com/), that can perform the decryption for users.

Comment: Do you think this would work better on crypto stack exchange?

Comment: @baordog He's pretty much just asking if anyone's analyzed this particular piece of malware.  Not sure the Crypto SE would know what to do with it.

Comment: I'm afraid that, even if "us" reverse-engineers would be able to reverse the malware to fully documented source code, we'd need the help of "them" crypto guys to attack it; and there was no way to succeed unless the malware writers messed up somewhere. Openssl has been open source for >10 years and we still don't know how to sniff TLS traffic.

Comment: In fact, it seems that the cipher algorithm used by CTB-Locker has a few weaknesses and the context in which the cipher occurs is a bit peculiar because you may imagine to have access to some couple (ciphertext, cleartext) if you have a (partial) backup of your system. The point here is to recover precisely the encryption scheme of CTB-Locker to see if there is a way to break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [full analysis of the cipher algorithm of CTB-Locker](https://zairon.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/ctb-locker-encryptiondecryption-scheme-in-details/) performed by [Zairon](https://zairon.wordpress.com/).

He's not really optimistic about the possibility to cryptanalyse the files as the first paragraph of the blog post is the following:

> After my last post about CTB-Locker I received a lot of e-mails from people asking for a complete analysis of the malware. Most of them wanted to know if it’s possible to restore the compromised files without paying the ransom. The answer is simple: it’s impossible without knowing the Master key! That key resides on the malicious server and it’s the only way to restore every single compromised file.

And, follow a full analysis of the encryption scheme of CTB-Locker. A good reading for anybody wants to know more about it !

- [CTB-Locker encryption/decryption scheme in details](https://zairon.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/ctb-locker-encryptiondecryption-scheme-in-details/), by Zairon, February 17, 2015.